# Need help to understand ctree plot warnings()

Tags: r, party

First time asking a question.

I am relatively new to using R. Using it on a project for the Party package (cforest, ctree) which has no implementation in Python.

I receive no warnings in my code until I plot a ctree, at which point I get a varying number of the same two warnings each time I plot a new ctree. The two types of warnings are shown below:

Warning messages:

> In model@fit(data, ...) : cmvnorm: completion with ERROR > EPS
>
> In model@fit(data, ...) : cmvnorm: N > 1000 or N < 1

I’ve determined these warnings are coming from the libcoin package, but I don’t understand them.

To be clear, I am getting a plot. The results seem reasonable. I just want to know what these warnings are trying to convey so I can know to disregard or not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Comment: As @camille already pointed out: It's hard to help without a minimal self-contained reproducible example. But one thing you might try out is to use the newer `partykit` package rather than the old `party` package. This has lots of improvements in `ctree()` and might avoid the problem because of a completely different internal structure.